# How to open a LTspice encrypted .mod file in LTspice XVII?

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, model

i want to use a capacitor model in LTspice XVII. 
On the [TDK webpage](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/technicalsupport/tvcl/general/mlcc.html) are a lot of models of their capacitors.

I chose the DC bias model (LTspice) of the C3216 commercial grade (up to 50V) C3216X5R1V226M160AC capacitor.
After downloading the [.rar file](https://product.tdk.com/info/tvcl/ltspice/mlcc_commercial_general_c3216_ltspice.zip) i extracted all models in my \LTspice\lib\sum\TDK\C3216 directory.

The .mod file is encrypted for LTspice.
So i will not be able to read all specs of their capacitor, but i can use it as 'black box' model at least.
The problem is that my LTspice is not able to open the .mod file.
[image]

I don't know why! 
The first line of the .mod file says:

`* LTspice Encrypted File
* This encrypted file has been supplied by a 3rd
* party vendor that does not wish to publicize
* the technology used to implement this library.
* Permission is granted to use this file for
* simulations but not to reverse engineer its
* contents.`

In the file C3216X5R1V226M160AC.asy i found the line:

```
SYMATTR ModelFile C3216X5R1V226M160AC_b_LTspice.mod
```

So it should find the .mod file...

I am using LTspiceXVII on win10 x64.

Comment: Where did you place the `.mod` file? If you placed it in `Program Files` (or wherever the default installation is), it won't work. XVII creates a second path in `My Documents`, though I wouldn't recommend. It may be better to simply extract them in the folder where your project resides. Placing the symbol is done through `F2 > Top Directory` drop-down menu. I just tried and it worked for me. If it's another cause, skip this.

Comment: You are right! The place where the .mod file is was the problem. The .mod files where placed in 'user\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sym\myC'.
Now i placed the .mod files in 'user\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sub' and it works! Answer the question and i will mark it as solved! Thanks you

Comment: Yeah, I agree, answers need to be answers not comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just copy-paste my comment, if you say that did it. If it ain't broken...

---

Where did you place the .mod file? If you placed it in `Program Files` (or wherever the default installation is), it won't work. XVII creates a second path in `My Documents`, though I wouldn't recommend. It may be better to simply extract them in the folder where your project resides. Placing the symbol is done through `F2 > Top Directory` drop-down menu. I just tried and it worked for me. If it's another cause, skip this.